# Symfony2.8: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.8

I know that people have asked about it many times but I really don't know how to solve it.

I think a mistake is somewhere in a method inside the Controller:

```
/**
 * View action.
 *
 * @param Website $website Website entity
 * @param Request $request
 * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request HTTP Request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response HTTP Response
 * @internal param Rating $rating
 * @Route(
 *     "/{id}",
 *     name="website_view",
 * )
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function viewAction(Website $website, Request $request)
{
    $websiteId = $this->get('app.repository.website')->findOneById($website)->getId();
    $rating = new Rating();
    $form = $this->createForm(RatingType::class, $rating);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $rating->setWebsite($websiteId);
        $this->get('app.repository.rating')->save($rating, $website);
        $this->addFlash('success', 'message.created_successfully');

    }

    return $this->render(
        'website/view.html.twig',
        ['website' => $website,
            'rating' => $rating,
            'form' => $form->createView()]
    );
```

The problematic line is:

```
            $rating->setWebsite($websiteId);
```

It doesn't set the website id to rating if the line is missing but when the line is added I get above error.

I have necessary getters and setters in Rating entity and save method with persist and flush in Rating Repository.

Could the problem be the fact that I've placed this method in Website Controller instead of Rating Contoller?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this function with website object as argument instead of website id

```
...
public function viewAction(Website $website, Request $request)
{
    $websiteId = $website->getId();
    ...
    $rating->setWebsite($website);
    ...
}
```